# Using two plastic cups for Kiddush

Tags: halacha, shabbat, kiddush, kiddush-cup

I know [making kiddush with a plastic cup](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9601) is problematic because of requirements. I have seen people using two plastic cups: What is the source for this and is it legitimate?

Comment: What are those "requirements"?

Comment: to have a real keli

Comment: @yydl see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9601. (Yes, I know it's your own question. I'm just `@yydl`ing you so others know that this link relates to your comment here.)

Comment: @msh210 Wow. thanks. I didn't even notice my comment

Comment: You know, or you believe?

Comment: Check this out -- http://torahmusings.com/2012/08/disposable-dishes/

Comment: Ummmm, I do it all the time, since, I've seen others do it all the time, ummmm? Anyway, I'm a istaneese, eh, so I'm patour from being normal. If I had my own kiddush cup that only I use tha'd be a different story now wouldn't it?

Answer (score 8):

At the end of [this pdf](http://www.bknw.org/uploads/5/9/9/5/5995719/kiddush_using_disposable_cups-2.pdf) (referenced [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9601/are-disposable-cups-allowed-for-kiddush-or-havdalah/9602#9602)), he says:

> There does not seem to be any basis for the idea of doubling up a cup, as this
>   does not cause the cup to be used more times than it otherwise would have been used.

Answer (score 8):

I'm [cross-posting my answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9629/1059) as well.

R' Meir Goldwicht of Yeshiva University addressed this in a Q&A a number of years ago.  He felt that doubling a cup does absolutely nothing to solve the problem of the plastic cup not having "Kayamus" as he called it (permanence).  He also called into question whether having a plastic cup in the first place was really a problem, since people do refill them and even wash and save them.  Since the point of plastic cups is that they *could* be thrown away, he suggested it was better to use something more permanent, but he did not feel it invalidated the Kiddush to use a single plastic cup.

Answer (score 5):

R. Dov Lior answers the question here: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=62394

He says that: When one uses 2 cups, the outer cup is considered a utensil that serves the inner cup, and it will not be thrown away immediately, which perhaps solves the problem of R. Moshe that a single plastic cup is thrown away immediately and is therefore not appropriate for kiddush. However, he says he is not sure this really solves the problem.

Comment: Was Rav Moshe referring to a plastic or a paper cup?  In his day, paper cups were more common, and were very flimsy.

Answer (score 3):

The double-cup is supposed to give it more significance. I've seen many a significant rabbi do this.  Sorry, don't have sources off-hand.

Comment: can you name theses rabbis? or ask them where they got it from

Comment: And do you know why they did it? Perhaps they just couldn't separate the two plastic cups, as often happens.

Comment: @msh210, no; it was specifically to give it more significance.

Comment: Many, many people do this, some who are very prominent. But that doesn't mean that doubling a plastic cup somehow gives it more significance other than in the mind of the person doing the doubling.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Heinemann answered in a *shiur*, "Rav Moshe says that using a plastic cup for Kiddush is not *lechatchila* because it is similar to a *kos pogum*.  Even if you put one plastic cup into a second, that doesn’t help – you’re doubling the problem of having two *kos pogums*. **The reason some people might put one plastic cup into a second one is because they want to avoid getting wet in case there is a crack in one of the cups.**"